# GetItem with AsyncStorage in React Native is not working

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, asyncstorage

I am new in react native and getting the bind value at index 1 is null when I am trying to get data from AsyncStorage in react-native below is my code.

```
Alert.alert(
        'Info',
        'React AsyncStorage',
        [
            {text: 'Get Data',onPress: () => this.getValue('name'),},
            {text: 'Save Data', onPress: () => this.saveValue('name', 'abc'),}
        ],
        {cancelable: false},
        );


async saveValue(key:String, value:bool) {
     AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value);
     Alert.alert('Data', 'saving');         
}
async getValue(key) {         
    // try {
    //     await AsyncStorage.getItem(Constant.SHOW_INTRO).then((value) =>
    //         console.log(`AsyncStorage GET for Constant.SHOW_INTRO: "${value}"`));

    // } catch (error) {
    //     Alert.alert('Error', 'Error retrieving data');
    // }

    try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
        console.log(`AsyncStorage GET for "${key}": "${value}"`);
    } catch (error) {
        Alert.alert('Error', 'Error retrieving data');
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Hi @angel can you reproduce the issue on https://snack.expo.io ?

Comment: @MazinoSUkah I tried on your recommend website. This code is perfectly run on that. I can't find the issue with my environment.

Comment: please provide the link

Comment: My code is working fine on https://snack.expo.io/
I have problem with visual studio code environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this format:

```
setData = (value) => {
    // if value is an Object use this: value = JSON.stringify(value)
    // if value is a number use this: value = value.toString()
    AsyncStorage.setItem('myKey', value, () => {
        console.warn('Done!')
    })
}

getData = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('myKey').then(storage => {
        console.warn(storage)
    }).catch(e => console.warn(e))
}
```

Then:

```
this.setData('sample text')
```

**Edit:**

AsyncStorage takes some time to fetch data so it returns a promise until the value is available. You have to call the `then()` function and get the value from there. Anything inside the `then()` function is called after the value is retrieved from storage.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way:

```
async getValue(key){
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    console.log(`AsyncStorage GET for "${key}": "${value}"`);
  } catch (error) {
    Alert.alert('Error', 'Error to retrieve data');
  }
}
```

Comment: @Angel then can you post the whole Component / chunk of code so we know the full context please ?

Comment: I think this is an issue related to Android itself and not React Native.

Comment: Are you aware about what is my environment issue?
Because this code is perfectly run on https://snack.expo.io/ website

Comment: @Angel maybe it's something related to JSC https://github.com/react-native-community/jsc-android-buildscripts