# React native: Is AsyncStorage reactive?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I tried setting an item on login page

```
onSelectServer = async selected => {
    this.setState({
      selected_server: selected
    });

    console.log(selected);
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        "@SelectedServer:key",
        JSON.stringify(selected)
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
```

Then try to retrieve it on home screen

```
componentDidMount(){
      try {
          AsyncStorage.getItem("@SelectedServer:key").then(val => {
            const data = JSON.parse(val);

            console.log(data);
          });
        } catch (er) {
          console.log(er);
        }
}
```

It seems that its not reactive, I have to reload the app to make it work. Is there any alternative ways, or I have to use redux state as placeholder until it reloads.

Comment: when you go to the home screen, could you show the code?

Comment: Its there, its on componentdidmount

Comment: You should navigate to the home screen. After the completion of onSelectServer method.

Comment: instead of componentDidMount try to use componentDidUpdate. It invoked immediately after updating occurs & you have to control your logic inside that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetItem with AsyncStorage in React Native is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56181457/getitem-with-asyncstorage-in-react-native-is-not-working)